# Execute javascript on web page with frames using VBA

Tags: javascript, vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to execute javascript on an IE 11 web page that contains frames and I am using VBA to execute the javascript. This is my first attempt so I am probably making some rookie mistakes. The action I am trying to automate is pressing a "+" sign on a folder to expand it. I have seen a lot of discussion on this topic and I have tried to include what I think is relevant to my code. But after many attempts, I still cannot get it to work. The VBA code I am trying to get to work is as follows. Each call below to execScript has been an attempt to execute the javascript. The VBA error message that I received is placed as a comment before each call.
Thanks in advance for any help that you can offer.

```
    Dim doc             As MSHTML.IHTMLDocument
    Dim Frames          As MSHTML.IHTMLFramesCollection2
    Dim Window          As MSHTML.IHTMLWindow2

    ie.Navigate "URL of my web page"
    Set doc = ie.Document


    ' Error: Method 'frames' of object JScriptTypeInfo failed.

    Call ie.Document.Frames(0).execScript("populateNode(document.getElementById('treeViewRootNode_Home_0_children'),treeView_Data,document.getElementById('treeViewRootNode_Home_0'),'treeViewRootNode_Home_0');", "JavaScript")

    ' Error: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101.

    Call ie.Document.Frames.Item(0).execScript("populateNode(document.getElementById('treeViewRootNode_Home_0_children'),treeView_Data,document.getElementById('treeViewRootNode_Home_0'),'treeViewRootNode_Home_0');", "JavaScript")

    ' Error: Method 'frames' of object JScriptTypeInfo failed.

    Call ie.Document.Frames("navigationBodyFrame").execScript("populateNode(document.getElementById('treeViewRootNode_Home_0_children'),treeView_Data,document.getElementById('treeViewRootNode_Home_0'),'treeViewRootNode_Home_0');", "JavaScript")
```

Here is a portion of the HTML for the frame that I was able to grab with Firebug:

```
    <span id="treeViewRootNode_children" style="display:block">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <span id="treeViewRootNode_Home_children" style="display:block">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <span id="treeViewRootNode_Home_MyFolders_children" style="display:none">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <td>
                            <span id="treeViewRootNode_Home_0_spare"></span>
                            <span id="treeViewRootNode_Home_0_hidden" style="display: none"></span>
                            <a id="treeViewRootNode_Home_0" href="javascript:populateNode(document.getElementById('treeViewRootNode_Home_0_children'),treeView_Data,document.getElementById('treeViewRootNode_Home_0'),'treeViewRootNode_Home_0');">
                              <img id="treeViewRootNode_Home_0_lineImg" src="LineImages/lplus.gif" border="0">
                          </a>
                      </td>
                  <td nowrap="true">
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
      <span id="treeViewRootNode_Home_0_children" style="display:none"></span>
```

Comment: Why do you need VBA (VB Script?)? Why not pure javascript?

Comment: Maybe try `ie.Document.Frames(0).contentWindow.execScript "alert('ok')"`

Comment: Hi  @saille, I am trying to automate a Crystal Reports front end. My plan is post the report into Excel once I automate the report execution. VBA made the most sense to me given I am using Excel.

Comment: Hi @Tim-Williams, thank you for your suggestion. That line crashes with a "Method 'frames' of object JScriptTypeInfo failed".

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working today. Here is what I did, and there may be an easier way. If there is, I'd be interested in hearing about it.

Using the VBA debugger, I was able to figure out that there were multiple levels of frames in my web page.
Using firebug, I was able to figure out which frame contained the icon I wanted to press.
Here is the code that pressed the icon I needed to press.

```
Dim ie             As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim doc            As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim Frames         As MSHTML.IHTMLFramesCollection2
Dim Window         As MSHTML.IHTMLWindow2

ie.Navigate "URL of my web page"
Set doc = ie.Document
Set Window = doc.Frames(0).Frames(0).Frames(1).Frames(0)
Call Window.execScript("collapseHeader();", "JavaScript")

Set doc = Nothing
Set Window = Nothing
```